# Skip the error when calculating travel distances using for loop and georoute

Tags: r, loops, error-handling, geocoding

I am using taRifx.geo package in R to calculating driving distances between to addresses. What I am doing is putting the start points and end points in two columns of a dataframe. In my understanding georoute can only calculate one pair of distances at one time so I wrote a for loop to calculate all the pairs in the dataframe. But when there is an error the loop stops.

What I want is not stopping the loop but just put value NA value in the distance vector when it encounters an error and continues from the next pair. I know I should use something as tryCatch but I don't know how to write the code here. Anyone could help? Really appreciated!

```
library(taRifx.geo)

distance=data.frame(matrix(0,200,1))

for(i in 1:200){

  distance[i,1]=as.matrix(georoute( c(as.character(address$capitol[i]),
                          as.character(address$capitol_destination[i])),
                        verbose=TRUE, returntype="distance",
                        service="bing" ))

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, I will try your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tryCatch(as.matrix(georoute( c(as.character(address$capitol[i]),
                           as.character(address$capitol_destination[i])),
                           verbose=TRUE, returntype="distance",
                           service="bing" )),  error=function(a) {"."} )
```

Comment: While code is nice, it would be even better if you could explain how your solution works.